# communication between 2 LIghtning web componets, passing dynamic parameter from Parent to chlid LWC using Events

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I would like to send record Id(Seminar ID dynamically from for each) from Parent LWC to Child LWC
**Template Code:**

```
<lightning-tile key={seminar.Id}>   
  <lightning-layout key={seminar.Id}> 
    <lightning-layout-item >  
      <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="custom-box slds-grid img-style" data-recordid={seminar.Id} data-recordname={seminar.Name} data-schedulename={seminar.Description__c}  key={seminar.Id} value={seminar.Image__c} onclick={openModal}>
```

### Custom Event Created:

```
openModal(event) {
    this.seminarId = event.target.dataset.recordid;
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', **{ detail: {seminarId}**, });
    // Dispatches the event.
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
```

Now here in detail tag I want to send seminarid to child.
But I am getting error like 'SeminarId not defined.
[image]

Please some one help me how to fix this.

Comment: Editior not supporting to add detail Template code. Sorry for Inconvienence

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a small change in your code. `{seminarId}` needs to change with `this.seminarId`. Read more on this keyword in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```
openModal(event) {
    this.seminarId = event.target.dataset.recordid;
    // {seminarId} needs to change with 'this.seminarId'
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: this.seminarId });
    // Dispatches the event.
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
```

> Note:- You need to fire an event only when you are passing data from
>   child to parent. When you have to pass data from parent to child, you
>   will not need to fire event.

Examples:-

1. [PASSING DATA FROM PARENT TO CHILD COMPONENT](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/07/24/lwc-communication-part-1-passing-data-from-parent-to-child-component/)
2. [PASSING DATA FROM CHILD TO PARENT IN LWC](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/08/07/lwc-communication-part-2-passing-data-from-child-to-parent-in-lwc/)